# Web application error when i try to clear the cache

Tags: jsp, jsf, jakarta-ee, servlets, scriptlet

In my web application i clear the cache of the web pages with these instructions

```
<%
response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache,no-store,private,must-revalidate,max-stale=0,post-check=0,pre-check=0"); 
response.addHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); 
response.addDateHeader ("Expires", 0);
%>
```

But if I press the button ("Back") of the browser, it does not load the page more(The web pages expired).
[image]
How can i solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use JSF 1.2 or higher you need change it like this:

```
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
</h:head>
```

it can be part of template.xhtml